# angular testing get element by text

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular8

I'm trying to write unit tests for an angular 8 application. Inside spec file of a component (navbar.component.spec.ts) I want to click buttons. I want to get buttons by **inner text** of them. **How could I do that ?**

I'm using `*ngFor` Only way I can think of is giving ids and using ids like `const buttonElem = debug.query(By.css('#asd'));`

Comment: buttonElem.textContent

Comment: I want to get buttonElem by its textContent. I don't want to read textContent after I get buttonElem

Comment: Ah okay, might be not the best solution: Iterate over all buttons, look for textContent and return the corresponding button node. There is no css-selector for element contents

Comment: that's kind of acceptable thank you I will try that